# How to prevent a Div from fading-in before click

Tags: jquery

I would like to make a div fade in once I click a button which switches divs out. My issue is that when i click on the button there is no fade in as the content already faded in whilst it was "hidden". How can I make it so that the Div fades in once I press on the button and the Div is switched out?

Jcript:

```
// First Div

$(".N1, .N2, #N3").hide().each(function(i) {

    $(this).delay(i*500).fadeIn(750);
});


$('button').on('click', function(){

    $('.AboutP1').addClass('hidden');
    $('.AboutP2').removeClass('hidden');
});

// Second Div

$(".N4, .N5, #N6").hide().each(function(i) {

    $(this).delay(i*1500).fadeIn(1500);
});
```

Hope there is enough information here :)

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle. It is much easier to understand and don't mix up classes and ids.

Comment: Set the hide as an animation fade out (but super fast) and on complete fade the other one in.

Comment: Try using jQuery [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) instead of adding the class "manually"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be interested in jQuery's `.fadeToggle()`: http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/

Here's one solution to fade content from one div to another and back again 
 on a button click:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  if ($('.AboutP1').is(":visible")) {
    $('.AboutP1').fadeToggle(500, "linear", function() {
      $('.AboutP2').fadeToggle(500, "linear");
    });
  } else {
    $('.AboutP2').fadeToggle(500, "linear", function() {
      $('.AboutP1').fadeToggle(500, "linear");
    });
  }
});

$('.AboutP2').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Button</button>
<div class="AboutP1">AboutP1</div>
<div class="AboutP2">AboutP2</div>
```

Comment: @TimothyKA does this accomplish what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yes, it is close to what I am trying to accomplish! I will play around with it a bit!

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should work for you:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('#toggle').on('click', function()
  {
    $('.AboutP1').fadeTo(1000, 0, function()
    {
        $('.AboutP1').addClass('hidden');
        $('.AboutP2').removeClass('hidden').fadeTo(30000, 100);
    });
  });
});
```

You'll probably need to start `.AboutP2` out with an opacity of 0 (set in the css).

Here is a fiddle, you can play with the fade in/out times.  https://jsfiddle.net/ue2p01gv/